# How to add namespace into Model MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created folder "App_Code" in my project, with simple class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Tools
{

    public static class TextTools
    {
        public static void GenerateHash(string str, int user)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I add this namespace "Tools" with all classes and methods to my project? I tried to insert `using Tools;` in my AccountModels.cs but it isn't working.

Regards

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is this file within you MVC-project, or is it in some other class-library?

Comment: I created in my MVC-project another folder - `App_Code`. Then I insert into this folder class TextTools.cs with namespace 'Tools'. I want to use method from this namespace in my MVC-project. Error - `The type or namespace name 'Tools' could not be found`

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to set this ("Tools") as your projects default namespace?

Comment: I see no problem with your code, and in an MVC project your classes could reside pretty much anywhere, so I believe this should work. Is the file/folder referenced in your project?

Comment: No. I just want to add additional namespace ("tools"), and using methods from this namespace in my project.

Comment: did you build your project with the new class?

Comment: How can I add this reference to this folder?

Comment: Do you see the file/folder in the Solution Explorer in VS? In that case you already have the reference, since they reside in the same project. If you don't see the file there, then right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, choose Add -> Existing item (Shift + Alt + A), browse to your file and add it.

Comment: Did you set the Build Action of the class file to 'Compile'?

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to add "Tools" in your reference